# Reproducting the Repeated Augmentation method based on tensorflow-2

Tags: tensorflow

The `Repeated Augmentation` method was build based on `pytroch` framework `in origin`. However, how to implement it based on `Keras` or `tensorflow` framework was still a problem. The Repeated Augmentation method was came from the paper "MultiGrain: a unified image embedding for classes and instances".

The pytorch version code was stated in follows:

```
class RASampler(torch.utils.data.Sampler):
    """Sampler that restricts data loading to a subset of the dataset for distributed,
    with repeated augmentation.
    It ensures that different each augmented version of a sample will be visible to a
    different process (GPU)
    Heavily based on torch.utils.data.DistributedSampler
    """

    def __init__(self, dataset, num_replicas=None, rank=None, shuffle=True):
        if num_replicas is None:
            if not dist.is_available():
                raise RuntimeError("Requires distributed package to be available")
            num_replicas = dist.get_world_size()
        if rank is None:
            if not dist.is_available():
                raise RuntimeError("Requires distributed package to be available")
            rank = dist.get_rank()
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.num_replicas = num_replicas
        self.rank = rank
        self.epoch = 0
        
        self.num_samples = int(math.ceil(len(self.dataset) * 3.0 / self.num_replicas))
        self.total_size = self.num_samples * self.num_replicas
        # self.num_selected_samples = int(math.ceil(len(self.dataset) / self.num_replicas))
        self.num_selected_samples = int(math.floor(len(self.dataset) // 256 * 256 / self.num_replicas))
        self.shuffle = shuffle

    def __iter__(self):
        # deterministically shuffle based on epoch
        g = torch.Generator()
        g.manual_seed(self.epoch)
        if self.shuffle:
            indices = torch.randperm(len(self.dataset), generator=g).tolist()
        else:
            indices = list(range(len(self.dataset)))

        # add extra samples to make it evenly divisible
        indices = [ele for ele in indices for i in range(3)] # 重复3次
        indices += indices[:(self.total_size - len(indices))]
        assert len(indices) == self.total_size

        indices = indices[self.rank:self.total_size:self.num_replicas]
        assert len(indices) == self.num_samples

        return iter(indices[:self.num_selected_samples])

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_selected_samples

    def set_epoch(self, epoch):
        self.epoch = epoch
```

I have searched the reproduction code of RA method, however, `all of them` was based on `pytorch framework`. The `Repeated Augmentation (RA) method` was focused on the `distribution training strategy`. I am not familiar with the distribution training strategy, that I cannot reproduct it by myself.  Maybe somebody can give me some suggestions for reproduct the Repeated Augmentation method based on Keras or Tensorflow framework. With thanks for the helping.

Comment: Can you reduce this down to a runnable program that reproduces the problem? Tensorflow has  tf.distributed.MirroredStrategy for using multiple GPUs. That is probably what you need to replace the distribution training strategy. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras

Comment: That is a good idea. However, how to conduct the different augmentation to distribution workers.

For Example:
`def create_variable():
  if not x:
    x.append(tf.Variable(1.))
  return x[0]
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(["GPU:0", "GPU:1"])
with strategy.scope():
  _ = create_variable()
  print(x[0])`
As stated in the above-mentioned code, the **MirroredStrategy** was transmitted the same data to GPU workers. So, the generation different augmentation data was also a problem for distribution training.

Comment: " As stated in the above-mentioned code" I do not know which code you're referring to. Did you check tf.distribute? It has different strategies. You're most likely to get a good answer if you can create an example. Are you saying you want to use multiple gpus with different augmentations, but the MirroredStrategy uses the same augmentations?

Comment: Yes, you are right.    I want to use multiple gpus with different augmentations, but the MirroredStrategy uses the same augmentations.    How to transmit different augmented data to different GPUs, those different augmented result cames from the same one raw data.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with the claim. Traditionally if I am generating augmented data, then it will get used on the different gpus with the mirrored strategy. It seems like if you set it up correctly, and your augmentations are part of your pipeline it should get distributed.

Comment: Ok, maybe MirroredStrategy's `experimental_distribute_dataset` method can solve my problem.